# jQuery can't read cookie using jquery.cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

Hy,

I'm developing a website in ASP.NET MVC 5 on my local machine. I'm trying to read a cookie, which I've set by the backend. jQuery and the cookie plugin is included in my code. My code:

```
var test = $.cookie['test'];
```

The cookie "test" exist with following properties:

- Name: test
- Value: test
- Domain: localhost
- Path: /
- Expires: Session

I've read many posts about issues with cookies, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.cookie` is a function so you need to invoke it(by using () at the end), you are trying to read a property called `test`

```
var test = $.cookie('test');
```